# How to grant a role to a user during development?

Tags: php, security, symfony, firewall, roles

Is it possible to grant a role to the current user (me) dynamically?

I'm working on a website on my local computer, a server is hosting the production version of a website. The 2 versions (`dev` and `prod`) use an authentication system which use a CAS server, we changed the firewall to avoid this authentication system in `dev` environment. But when working locally I am only logged in as  an anonymous user, the firewall is configured to allow access to the administration to an anonymous user only if he is connected from the `127.0.0.1` address. So I can see any part of the administration but I can't simulate the access from the different roles during the development.

In other words, I'm looking for something like this:

```php
class AcmeController
{
    public AcmeAction()
    {
        ...
        $user->setRole('ROLE_ADMIN');
        ...
    }
}
```

Or any other way to set the role.

**Update:**

I tested this:

```php
class AcmeController
{
    public AcmeAction()
    {
        ...
        $user = $this->getUser();
        $user->setRole('ROLE_ADMIN');
        ...
    }
}
```

This brings a fatal error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function addRole() on a non-object in [...]AcmeController.php on line [...]

I think it's due to the fact the current user is anonymous so it doesn't exist in the DB and I can't access to the `User` object.

Comment: Why not just grant the `user` `ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN` and define it in `role_hierarchy` within `security.yml` so it wraps **all** roles?

Comment: @jperovic : that's already the case, but I don't know how to grant this role when l'm not logged in at all.

Comment: If you're not logged, you can't use $this->getUser(), it will return null... Why didn't get the user from your database ? $user=$em->getRepository('AppAcmeBundle:User')->find(YOUR_ID); ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to load any user from the database by using the `User` entity directly in `dev` environment and using a SSO/LDAP bundle in `prod` environment.

The solution was to change configuration files in order to use different login controllers in `dev` and `prod` environments:

<kbd>app/config/security.yml</kbd>: where the variables will be loaded

```
security:
    [...]
    providers:
        %security_providers%
    firewalls:
        dev:
            [...]
        user_manager: %security_firewalls_user_management%
```

<kbd>app/config/config_dev.yml</kbd> and <kbd>app/config/config_test.yml</kbd>: the variables are declared

The login use a traditional login form

```
parameters:
    security_providers:
        user_db:
            entity:
                class: Acme\AcmeBundle\Entity\User
                property: id
    security_firewalls_user_management:
        pattern:    ^/
        anonymous: ~
        form_login: ~
        logout: ~
        switch_user: true
    login_controller: "AcmeDevBundle:Security:login"
```

<kbd>app/config/config_prod.yml</kbd>: the variables are declared

```
parameters:
    security_providers:
        user_auth:
            entity:
                class: Acme\AcmeBundle\Entity\User
                property: other_id
   security_firewalls_user_management:
        pattern: ^/
        anonymous: ~
        trusted_sso:
            manager: user_sso
            login_action: false
            logout_action: false
            check_path: /
            login_path: page_login
        logout: true
        switch_user: true
    login_controller: "AcmeBundle:Main:login"
```

<kbd>app/AppKernel.php</kbd>

```
class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array(
            [...]
        );

        if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
            [...]
            # Bundle only activated in dev and test environments
            $bundles[] = new Acme\DevBundle\AcmeDevBundle();
        }

        return $bundles;
    }
[...]
```

The `DevBundle` is only loaded in `dev` and `test` environments, it uses a [traditional login form](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#using-a-traditional-login-form) and display a list of users than I can impersonate.